# Is there a way to force chrome keep showing or hiding the "https://" part?

Tags: google-chrome

I am running chrome Version 77.0.3865.120 on macOS.

when chrome finished to load a page, it looks like this figure

[image]

when I try to select part of the URL, it becomes like this

[image]

It takes and wastes me another click/tap, which is boring and inefficient. Is there a way to force chrome keep showing or hiding the "https://" part?

Comment: Interesting question. The question behind it would be why on Earth they have started hiding things. Maybe it could be related to the "_Web 2.0_" craze and to the Chinese flooding with Mobile Software Applications that are actually Tiny-Little Web-Browsers.

Comment: Flagging this as duplicate of [Chrome address bar no longer shows protocol or www subdomain](https://superuser.com/questions/1333575/chrome-address-bar-no-longer-shows-protocol-or-www-subdomain), because the current answer is outdated, and the linked question has new workarounds. (Let's keep it all in one place.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable this "friendly" option of Chrome, enter in the address bar these
two URLs:

```
chrome://flags/#omnibox-ui-hide-steady-state-url-trivial-subdomains
chrome://flags/#omnibox-ui-hide-steady-state-url-scheme
```

and mark both as Disabled, then click Relaunch Now.

These are "experimental" flags, so it is unknown how long they will keep on working.

Comment: Another relevant flag: `#omnibox-ui-hide-steady-state-url-path-query-and-ref`

Comment: Well, it was nice while it lasted, but all three flags are gone now. New readers: refer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1333575/chrome-address-bar-no-longer-shows-protocol-or-www-subdomain) for other workarounds (I've flagged this question as duplicate to keep it all in one place).